# Installing software (Realplayer) not from 'software' - is my missing package THAT important?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

Can someone explain this line I got when trying to install Realplayer on 16.04:

```
.......depends on lsb (>= 3.1); however:   Package lsb is not installed.
```

Clearly 'lsb 3.1' is a package of some sort, but why did I not get it with the install? Is it necessary, and if so **how do I get it?**

Realplayer is the only thing I miss from Windows so I'd be overjoyed if I could get it back.

Comment: That line means in order realplayer to be installed,it depends on package `lsb` that is greater or equal to version 3.1 for its functionality,that means below v3.0 won't work with realplayer, however package `lsb` is not installed on your system! that is called `unmet dependence error`,,Provide some info that @Zanna asked you above so that you can be helped to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the package, to get it just do `sudo apt-get install lsb`

That doesn't guarantee that realplayer would work at all. Even if it does start you may face plenty of issues. It's been discontinued about 6 years ago. [This blog post on **their** website](http://www.real.com/resources/linux-media-player/) says look for alternatives. [This archeive here](https://www.helixcommunity.org/projects/player/2005/downloads/index.html) has the old realplayer versions but it says clearly that to get them to work you have to check their code and compile.

My advice is go for VLC. I used it on windows and I use it daily on ubuntu and it's never let me down. I had videos with strange codecs, they didn't work on any player but VLC got them to play *(almost hehe)*